# Sending multiple transactions conveniently

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I need to allow users to upload CSVs to a (private network) ethereum-based token. CSVs could include hundreds and potentially thousands of rows. At present, a user must approve each individual transaction (eg: through MetaMask), which means each upload could necessitate hundreds & occasionally thousands of approval clicks.

We're looking to implement a solution that allows users to approve multiple transactions with one click. I've tried using createBatch/executeBatch, but at least with Metamask, it's still asking me approve each row independently.

So, what's the standard way of going about this? Is there one? A few notes:

- We're running on a private network, gas price isn't a huge concern
- We realize there's an argument for uploading entire CSVs as single transactions. We'd rather not do that, both for the sake of searchability and for consistency with non-CSV data, the majority of which will be uploaded as 1 transaction per row.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Though this bloat isn't required.
Instead of storing them in an array, you can simply call (address).transfer(value) for each row of csv and deploy a smart contract to send ether.
Beware that use only 100 transfers in a single call, otherwise you may encounter blockgaslimit.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract SendBCF {
    address public owner;

    struct OldToken {
        uint256 value;
        address member;
    }

    event FundsReceived(uint256 amount);

    event PaymentSent(address addr, uint256 amount);

    OldToken[] public oldTokenList;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function () public payable onlyOwner {
        /* Determine how much to pay each shareholder. */
        emit FundsReceived(msg.value);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function send2() public {
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value:120000000000000000, member:0x6Dc44076Ee3E3fAdC3DF35fF047eA5E5D59B2Caa}));
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value:120000000000000000, member:0x4a3e34cE7E79c47638c9053A776127271a1fFfe9}));
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value:120000000000000000, member:0xeE088601eA16C61974dD737Ca742342D6D8a3271}));
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value:120000000000000000, member:0xDf1D8265EA5E858322e1fd1b67f2D4AC63A31FC3}));
        oldTokenList.push(OldToken({ value:120000000000000000, member:0xa9DE9B27958bd66259368376FCca53fe2A12dd9D}));
    }

    function kill() public onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    function sendPayment() public {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < oldTokenList.length; i++) {
            oldTokenList[i].member.transfer(oldTokenList[i].value);
            emit PaymentSent(oldTokenList[i].member, oldTokenList[i].value);            
        }
    }
}
```